# Does "God said" (Gen. 1:1-3) imply a Fiat Creation since Jesus did miracles instantaneously by speaking too (Mtt 8:3)?

Tags: genesis, jesus, creation, healing

It seems at a cursory reading that God spoke things into existence immediately by simply expressing an imperative sentence, with immediate   results.

Does the conduct of Jesus years later give any insight hermeneutically as to how to answer this, when he did **creative miracles** as recorded in the N.T.? Jesus merely **spoke** and creative events took place instantly:

- Matthew 8:3 Jesus reached out and touched the man (leper)...immediately he was cured.
- Matthew 8:13 Jesus said to the centurion, "Go! It (healing servant) will be done just as you believed it would. And his servant was healed that very hour.
- Matthew 8:14-15 Peter's mother-in-law was lying in a bed with a fever, Jesus touched her hand and the fever left her, and she got up...
- Matthew 8:16 Demon possessed were brought to Him, and He drove out the spirits with a word.
- Matthew 8:26 Jesus got up and rebuked the winds and the waves, and it was completely calm.
- Matthew 8:31-32 The demons begged Jesus..."send us into the herd of pigs."  He said, "Go". So they came out and went...

It seems these were all instantaneous miracles requiring the formation of new organs, tissue, cells, tendons, etc., where there was none. And the writer John wrote that this **same Jesus was the one who created the universe** (John 1:1-3, *Through Him all things were made; without Him nothing was made...* See also Colossians1:16, *For by Him all things were created: things in heaven and on earth, visible and invisible...*) Does the tense of the verb in Genesis 1 require a specific interpretation?

To aid in answering this, it could be noted that the astronomer, Hugh Ross, declared that modern science has determined that the Creation of matter took just 1/100 of a billionth of a trillionth of a trillionth of a second! This was a deduction of scientists, not theologians! Does this have any bearing on interpreting Genesis 1 creation by Jesus?

Comment: "*And God said, Let there be light: and there was light.*" is the only instance of "God said" in Genesis 1:1–3,  If you are asking specifically about this (verse 3), almost everything in the body of this question is irrelevant. If you are asking about doctrinal interpretations of how that verse relates to other scripture, the question is more suitable for Christianity.SE.

Comment: @Ray Butterworth- The "body of this question" applies to the second half of the posted question: the Matthew 8 references underscore the FIAT ability of Jesus, which was the contention: Jesus could have "spoken everything into existence. If we consider the "Whole Counsel " of God,  Psalm 33:6,9 seems to bear this out. Should Matthew  (and Psalms) govern  how we interpret hermeneutically  Genesis 1:1-3? That is the crux of this post.

Comment: "Jesus was the one who created the universe" is from an incorrect and biased translation. The word for universe is actually 'ages' and universe or world is wrong. Jesus wasn't born yet - how could he make anything? John 1:1-3 does not mention Jesus. You can not change the Bible wording to suit your theology!

Comment: @Steve-In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God...All things were made by Him...In Him was life and the life was the Light of men...The Light shined in darkness, and the darkness comprehended it not...John came for a witness, to bear witness of the Light...That was the true Light which lights every man that comes into the world...He was in the world and the world was made by Him...He came to His own (Jews) and His own received Him not...John bare witness, This is He of whom I spoke..The next day John sees Jesus coming, said, Behold the Lamb of God! Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Jesus' words and the results which follow confirm the power of the divine nature.

As the Bible says:

> By the word of the LORD were the heavens made; and all the host of
> them by the breath of his mouth. . . . For he spake, and it was done; he commanded, and it stood fast. (Psalm 33:6,9, KJV)
>
> Let them praise the name of the LORD: for he commanded, and they were
> created. (Psalm 148:5, KJV)

The KJV expression "the LORD" actually represents the name of God (Yahweh) in Hebrew.  Jesus spoke as he was commanded by his Father, who is God; thus, Jesus' words had the same God-inspired power as those spoken during the six days of creation week.

As Jesus stated:

> For I have not spoken of myself; but the Father which sent me, he gave
> me a commandment, what I should say, and what I should speak. (John
> 12:49, KJV)

God's words have power, even when they are spoken through someone else!  Throughout the Bible, God's "word" is consistently shown to have creative, life-giving power.